# Understanding imports and scopes and caffe

Tags: python, python-import, caffe

I have the two files:

## main.py

```
import mylib

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myobj = mylib.MyObj(0)

def main():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.myobj.docaffe()
```

## mylib.py

```
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, gpuid):
        caffe.set_device(gpuid)
        self.nd = caffe.Net(...)

    def docaffe():
        self.nd.forward(...)
```

However, the code runs on the CPU despite the almost identical code in an alternative version of `mylib.py` (my two modules currently communicate via `zmq`, so I want to instead call directly) working as expected when invoked directly via `python mylib.py`.

So, is there something I don't know about importing modules and contexts? Do I need some extra scope information to make sure I'm setting GPU mode in the correct context?

**UPDATE**: I tried pasting the `mylib.py` into `main.py`, and the code still fails to use the GPU, so perhaps there is some obscure clash between `caffe` and other imports, like `cv2` or various ROS modules.

Answer (score 0):

That was bizarre - the solution for my problem was:

## mylib.py

```
import caffe

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, gpuid):
        caffe.set_device(gpuid)
        self.nd = caffe.Net(...)

    def docaffe():
        caffe.set_mode_gpu()
        self.nd.forward(...)
```

It didn't work moving `caffe.set_mode_gpu()` to either the start or end of the `__init__` method, it was only before calling the guts of `caffe` that it seemed to stick. I believe the problem was related to using threads and creating `MyObj` in one thread, but then using it in another.